# isset() function not working properly for me

Tags: php

So I have PHP code like this

```
if (isset($_POST['btnChange'])) {
    PHP CODE HERE
} else if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {
    PHP CODE HERE
} else {
    PHP CODE HERE FOR DELETE
}
```

My HTML code loks like this

```
<form action="decision.php" method="POST">
    SOME HIDDEN INPUTS AND ON TABLE
    <input type="submit" name="btnChange" value="Change">
    <input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="Update">
    <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

So the problem is that when I click each button I straight go for DELETE section (else), my code is not checking for if-s.
I checked my code and it is correct only problem is probably in if(isset).

Comment: What's the content of `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: Voted to close as typo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Belive it or not,

my form looked like this

```
<form action="decision.php" action="POST">
```

Instead of

```
<form action="decision.php" method="POST">
```

Thank you all for taking time for this and sorry for wating you time, I was to tired.

Comment: This is why it is so important to always show your _actual_ code, copy/pasted directly from your editor.

Comment: Yeah I know, but my code was so big and I check it and tought its all right...

Answer (score 3):

The displayed code look OK. Surely something you haven't shown us. 
Just try your lines in a simple test file to be sure.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_POST['btnChange'])) {
        echo 'btnChange';
    } else if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {
        echo 'btnUpdate';
    } else {
        echo 'else';
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="btnChange" value="Change">
    <input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="Update">
    <input type="submit" name="btnDelete" value="Delete">
</form>
```

Comment: This should be a comment (you can use websites such as 3v4l.org to provide linked samples).

Comment: After I added " if (!empty($_POST)) " I found my mistake, thank you friend, looks like I am to tired and done for today. All the best !!!